# Detect whether selection changed was called during binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, selectionchanged

What is the best way in C# and wpf to detect, whether comboboxes selection changed event was called during initial binding? I only want to handle something on selection changed when it is performed by the user over the ui.

Xaml without the binding part:

```
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="OnChanged" />
```

C#-Code:

```
private void OnChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Here i want to know, wheter called by using ui or from binding
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't call property setter from code then setter is only called by the binding.

Comment: I don't mean calling the setter, i mean calling the `SelectionChanged` event of the combobox.

Comment: Here's a simple idea: Fire up a different method! Is there no `OnBinding`-like event to listen to?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using event use binding

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

In viewmodel

```
SomeType _selectedItem;
public SomeType SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        // ... put your logic when user change selection here
    }
}
// use this to change selection from viewmodel
public SomeType SelectedItemSet
{
    set
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        // ... put your logic when selected item is set by viewmodel here
    }
}
```

Comment: But isn't that bad mvvm style, to put logic elements in the view models?

Comment: What is *logic element*? What exactly are you going to do when selection is changed by the user?

Comment: I want to write some thing to a log file. I could do it in the view-model, but maybe there is some other way. Thank you a lot :)